# Can't get this template to work

Tags: fonts, templates

I recently downloaded this CV template:
http://www.latextemplates.com/template/wilson-resume-cv

The download includes a "cv.tex", "structure.tex" and a folder with a bunch of fonts + a file called ".DS_STORE"(?)

I've never really downloaded any packages or fonts or any of that stuff before so I simply tried to compile the cv.tex file straight away but I get errors.

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "Erewhon-BoldItalic" cannot be found.
```

There's more but I don't know what is relevant. So where should I put these fonts to be able to compile?

Thank you for your patience.

EDIT: My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

EDIT 2: Compiling with other fonts like u said actually worked, so the template itself seems to be fine. I'll try to learn how to install new fonts then :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can use a font you have installed on your computer to test if the template compiles.  Then learn how to install fonts on your system (windows or linux, you didn't told us that) and try the new installed font.

Comment: If you just put the fonts in the same directory as the `.tex` file, `fontspec` should be able to find them without them being installed on the system. But installing them makes them accessible for any other document/program, so you may want to learn how to do that anyway.

Comment: BTW: the `.DS_STORE` file is an auxiliary file generated by Mac OS X (for previews and so on). You can safely delete it, as it has nothing to do with the actual `tex` files.

Answer (score 1):

The downloaded zip file *must* compile as it is, once it is extracted. Remember to use xelatex.

[image: CV]

On the other hand, if you want to use the attached fonts, just copy the otf files to your /home font folder, usually `/home/USER/.fonts`. If you don't find it, then there are two possibilities: either you have to tell nautilus to «unhide» files (then you'll see it), or you don't have one. In this case, all you have to do is create a new folder (right click or Ctrl+Shift+N) and name it `.fonts`.

[image: .fonts folder]

Comment: What makes it so that the downloaded zip file _must_ compile as-is?

Comment: @PaulGessler Maybe my phrasing was bad. I meant, that after download & extraction, the .tex file must compile and produce a PDF, whereas the OP stated that it didn't. I emphasized the verb in order to confirm that the CV template was working.

Comment: I know what you meant, but I still don't understand what guarantees that some random file downloaded from somewhere will compile. We have no idea what TeX installation/packages/versions the OP has.

Comment: @PaulGessler My fault. I should have specified that I was running Ubuntu as well.